# How to set a restriction for most pages

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code to load an `admin` page in Node.js file.

```
app.get('/admin',function(req,res){
    if(req.session.loggedIn == undefined)
    {
        res.writeHead(301, {
            Location: '/login'
        });
        res.end();
    }
    else
    {
         res.send("ADMIN PAGE");
    }
});
```

I will have several pages routed like this, where I check on the session if the user is logged in. If not, I'll redirect to the login page, if the user is logged I show the page.

Can I some how add the restriction to all pages (Except for the login page, of course), without repeating the code, to avoid changing in all routes if in the future, I have to add a new restriction?

Maybe I can use a regex right? but then how can I decide what to do in each rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a middleware function and include that wherever you need it. For example:

```
function requireLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session || req.session.loggedIn === undefined) {
    res.writeHead(301, { 'Location': '/login' });
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  next();
}
```

Then just use it in your routes wherever it makes sense, like:

```
app.get('/admin', requireLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.send('ADMIN PAGE');
});
```

Or you could use it in a separate router, pass it to `app.use()`, etc.